# Suggestions for migrating a backend codebase from JS to TS

Tags: typescript, backend

I am currently interning in the backend team of my company and I have been given the task of migrating the entire backend to TypeScript. It is currently in JavaScript (NodeJS, ExpressJS, MongoDB) and uses AWS and Redis. I have a good grip on JavaScript and I am familiar with the associated JavaScript frameworks as well. I have zero idea of TypeScript. I have just read and tried hands-on through the basic documentation of TypeScript.

Could anyone suggest some resources/blogs or any tips in general?

P.S. I don’t mind writing the entire backend in TypeScript from scratch. But this has to be the last option. I will be working on the migration of this codebase from the next week. In the meantime, I need to understand the entire code base.

Thanks in advance.

I tried a very brute-force method of changing it module by module and soon realized that it was not going to work. I was thinking of refactoring the routes for every API individually. Do let me know if there is a better method.

Comment: All JavaScript is valid TypeScript. Your experience with JS will make you more proficient in TS. Rewriting in TS means rewriting in JS. That's because doesn't change any JS behavior and all TS syntax is stripped from the output. There is a one to one correspondence between the two.